# Using Regular Expression find everything except two strings

Tags: regex

In my document I have

```
<Country>US</Country>
<Country>PR</Country>
```

Between the

```
<country>
```

and

```
</country>
```

I want to find ANYTHING except for US and PR.

For example

```
<country>US</country>   =  ignore
<country>PR</country>   =  ignore

<country>UP</county>    =  match found
```

What I have is

```
Pattern = "<Country>(.*?[^USPR].*?)</Country>"
```

but this ignores strings like

```
<Country>UP</Country>
```

Not sure how to write allowing only 2 options between the tags.. US and PR only.

Comment: It's 2013. Use an XML parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.

```
<country>(?!(US|PR))(.*?)</country>
```

Matches the opening `<country>` tag not followed by `US` or `PR`. Then goes on to match anything before the closing `</country>` tag.

Comment: Note: This is using a [look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). You can find more information on what that is and what it will do at the link.

Comment: There's no better site on Regex than regex info. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Wow got more than I asked for, this worked great!  Thank you for explaining it, and the info site.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
(?<=<Country>(?!US|PR)).*?(?=</Country>)
```